# Python Selenium - hot to get "Input" which going before the text inside the "td"

Tags: python, html, selenium

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
   <td class="formtext" colspan="3">
   <span class="required">*</span>
     Are you?
   </td>
   <td class="formtext" colspan="3">

   <input type="radio" value="M">
     Male
   <input type="radio" value="F">
     Female

   </td>
</tr>
```

**Python:**

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Are you?")]')[0].find_elements_by_xpath('./following::td[contains(text(),"Male")]//preceding-sibling::input')[0].click()
```

My current solution is working `[0].click() =  Male`, `[1].click() =  "Female"`

**Question:**
Instead of using `[0]` and `[1]`, how to set up so that if `text() == "Male"` the input before this text will be clicked, so this function will work based on **TEXT**

P.S. Please do not suggest using `value (M/F)`, I need to make it work based on TEXT

**I'm looking for something like this:**

**Male** will be clicked

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Are you?")]')[0].find_elements_by_xpath('./following::td[contains(text(),"Male")]//preceding-sibling::input')[0].click()
```

**Female** will be clicked

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Are you?")]')[0].find_elements_by_xpath('./following::td[contains(text(),"Female")]//preceding-sibling::input')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below in your xpath

```py
//td/text()[contains(.,'Male')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

This will give the text node which contains `Male` and then previous input for the same

Also if you are ok to use value you should using like below for selecting `Male` option

```py
//td/input[@type='radio'][@value='M']
```

Comment: Please modify your answer as your current solution will not work for "Female". And this will work `//td/text()[contains(.,'Male')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]`

Answer (score 0):

As [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) uses [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) it would be tough to identify the `<input>` tags based on the texts *Male*  or *Female*. As an alternative, to `click()` on the element related to the text **Male** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Male*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='formtext' and contains(.,"Are you")]//following::td[1]/input"))).click()
  ```
- *Female*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='formtext' and contains(.,"Are you")]//following::td[1]//following::input[2]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Please read the question, as your answer is NOT text dependant.